# Random Greek Symbols appears in pdf generated by LaTeX

Tags: symbols, pdf, greek

I use Texmaker. Once the `.pdf` file is generated by LaTeX, I notice that there are several greek symbols (mostly Sigma) in random places. Does any one know the reason? (My code does not contain these characters.)

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Could you please post the code for a [mini document](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces this?

Comment: Also post a screenshot of the produced document in case the behavior is not reproducible (e.g. it has something to do with the fonts, Operating System etc)